# superscript not working on App Bar

Tags: android, android-menu, android-textattributes

I am trying to add A+ (for font inc) and A-(for font dec) to my app bar:

works fine in in the menu but not on the App bar. The following are the details

I am trying the following:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/fontincrease"
    android:title="@string/fontincrease"
    app:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

and String is defined as

```
<string name="fontincrease">A<sup><small>+</small></sup></string>
```

On the App bar is shows

[image]

So its not showing correctly

Where as if i try instead of always i put never:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/fontincrease"
    android:title="@string/fontincrease"
    app:showAsAction="never"
/>
```

and String is not changed it shows

[image]

Comment: Most likely, that is a limitation in how the text is applied to the action bar button. For example, if you temporarily change the "Visit us" overflow item to appear as a text button, you will see `VISIT US`. `Button` forces all-caps for the text; this may also be breaking your desired superscript. Consider creating an icon that has your superscript and use that instead.

Comment: Can you suggest which site is good for create icons from text

Comment: Personally, I use Inkscape for that sort of work, though it is a desktop program, not a Web site.

Comment: ok. thank you. I have to find some icons

Comment: It's the `textAllCaps` value in the default style that's breaking that. If you create your own style with a `parent` of `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu`, set the `textAllCaps` to `false` in it, and set that style as the `actionMenuTextAppearance` in your theme, it should fix it. Though CommonsWare's suggestion of just creating an icon for it is probably the better option.